# Difficulty adding Quill link tooltip to custom theme

Tags: javascript, quill

I've been searching through the documentation for guidance on how to implement a link tooltip to a non standard theme (eg, not snow or bubble) but I'm running into problems.

Reading through the documentation [here](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#handlers) leads me to think I need to add a handlers object to `modules.toolbar` when initialising an instance of Quill, like so:

```
        let editor = new Quill(`#${id}-editor`, {
            bounds: element[0],
            formats:
                without(
                    ctrl.formats() ?
                        ctrl.formats()
                    : formats,
                    'paste',
                    'fullscreen'
                ),
            modules: {
                toolbar: {
                container: `#${id}-toolbar`,
                    handlers: {
                        link: ( value ) => {
                                if (value) {
                                    let href = 'http://www.google.nl';
                                    editor.format('link', href);
                                 } else {
                                    editor.format('link', false);
                                 }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

In my instance the handler function does get called when pressing the link button in the toolbar, but `value` is always `false`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `handlers` are called when toolbar buttons are clicked. The `value` parameter passed in is either true or false depending if that format exists over the current selection range. So if the user highlighted an existing link and clicked the link button, `value` will be false. Otherwise, it will be true. It can be a non-boolean value if the button has a `data-value` attribute but that is unrelated to your problem.

So in Snow for example, it adds a custom handler to show a link editor tooltip when `value` is true. When value is true, it simply calls the API to remove the link.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, the behavior you describe is not my experience. When I select some text in the editor and I click the link button, the `value` in the handler function is *always* `false`. It doesn't matter if the text I selected in the editor already has a link or not. Have I not configured the instance of the editor correctly?

Comment: Sorry I had the values incorrect but your code definitely works for me on Chrome: http://codepen.io/quill/pen/Wojmrv